# Javascript library to chart/graph electrophysiological data -large data over hours

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, data-visualization, bioinformatics

I'm looking to graph

- 500k datapoints
- The x axis is in milliseconds and I want to be able to label it in some format to show milliseconds: ex hh:mm:ss:msms
- I want to be able to zoom/pan in to see smaller segments of time

### more context

I have a 16-30mb json file. It has EOG data, which is like EEG, but it tracks eye movement instead of brain waves. The eog recording is from a night of sleep.

```json
[
   {millisecondsPassed: 188, EogReading:400},
   {millisecondsPassed: 230, EogReading:423}, 
   {millisecondsPassed: 399, EogReading:512},
   {millisecondsPassed: 443, EogReading:431},

   ...etc. 500k times...
]
```

### What I tried

I tried [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/). It is having a very hard time loading large amounts of data. It performs even worse I added `chartjs-zoom-plugin` to enable zoom.

I tried [dygraphs](https://dygraphs.com/) which doesn't seem to have a way to use custom x-axis labels so I can't show the time in milliseconds on the labels, the time is only shown in dates (June 10, 2021). But maybe I'm wrong and there is a way.

Is there a good graphing library for my use case or a way to utilize either of these libraries better?

Comment: have you looked at apexcharts or just plain d3js? and perhaps JS isn't right language for such large data sets. maybe you have more luck with pyton

Comment: dygraphs looks to have options for axis labeling, and it can be a date or a number field--maybe instead of using a date you should be using milliseconds (perhaps starting at 0 for the start of data).

Comment: @SuperDJ I haven't looks at either of those yet. My sense was js might be the wrong language, but I'm just so much more comfortable in js than python.

Comment: You need to write code that interacts with the graph displayed.  There are only a couple K pixels on a screen, so there is no sense trying to plot more.  Your data needs to be averaged down to, say 1500 points over the currently zoomed time axis.

Comment: @DaveNewton I will look more into it, I found an issue on the github that said it wasn't possible to but it was from 2016, maybe outdated.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss The docs I saw explicitly stated there are date and number axis labeling (w/o doing any customization); what I'm saying is that maybe "date" doesn't make much sense in this context--millis are a number, not a date :) But what ravenspoint said is more relevant (and I didn't post a similar comment)--that much data in a few thousand pixels is meaningless anyway; save sub-second visualization until it's actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a couple K pixels on a screen, so there is no sense trying to plot more points than will be visible.  You need code that looks at the current time axis, selects your data from that range, averages it down to, say, 1500 points, then plots it using any half decent plotting library.

Do not leave this work to a library!  Some will just draw on the same pixel over and over again. others will use their own averaging algorithm that you have no control over.

I am often amazed by questions that go "I have a tricky little problem, which library should I use to solve it - oh and the library has to be available for free."  Think about it: what do you suppose the quality of the code in a library is going to be when a) the coder knows nothing about your tricky problem and b) the coder is not going to be paid for the work.